# What is required for Powershell 2.0 to render a script's default parameter value in the help page?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, default-value

I have the following simple script that accepts text as input and writes it to the host.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Writes the input string to the host.
.PARAMETER Text
    The text to write to the host.
#>

param([string]$text = "hello world!")
Write-Host $text
```

To render the help for this script, I execute the following command within a Powershell session, where `write-text.ps1` is the name of this script.

```
get-help .\write-text.ps1 -full
```

In the following output, I am expecting to see the default value of the script's parameter listed in the help -- but I don't:

```
PARAMETERS
    -text <String>
        The text to write to the host.

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    1
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?
```

What do I need to add or change in this script for the help-engine to render the default parameter value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not show a default value using the comment based help.  You need to make a MAML help file to do that.

Comment: This is actually documented on MSDN (so does that make it a feature ? :-). Look under Troubleshooting at [about_Comment_Based_Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819489.aspx)

Comment: I think the reason for that was to just keep comment based help simple to write.

Comment: No, several properties of parameters (e.g. type) are picked up _from the code_ and integrated into the help output along with the developer's doc-comments. Default value should be one of these--completely transparent to the developer--so omitting it does not simplify writing doc-comments.

Comment: The default value and the wildcard acceptance is defined in the MAML help, not the code.  There is no use to have it in the code because they are not features provided by the PowerShell engine.  The comment based help is equivalent to the MAML help.  But to simplify things, they only implemented the parameter description in the comment based help.

Answer (score 3):

Script-based help can be picky, might be as simple as that you have capitalized the variable in the help text, but not that variable itself. A long shot, I know...

An alternative that I prefer is to but the description next to the parameter:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
MumbleMumble

.DESCRIPTION
Even more MumbleMumble

.EXAMPLE
PS> MumbleMumble
#>

function MumbleMumble
{
   param
   (
      #The in-parameter for MumbleMumble, as text
      $text
   )

   ...
}
```

I like this approach because it puts the description next to the parameter - and because it seems to work :).